# How to make a rectangle with drop shadow in Delphi using Skia4Delphi?

Tags: delphi, vcl, dropshadow, skia, skia4delphi

How can I draw a rectangle in Delphi using Skia that has a drop shadow?

I want something like this:

[image: Button drop shadow]

I am new to Skia and don't yet understand how to draw these kinds of things. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend you check project Samples that ship with Delphi. Amongst them there is one project sample that shows most of Skia functionality. If you haven't installed samples you can get it from [RADStudio12Demos GitHub](https://github.com/Embarcadero/RADStudio12Demos/tree/main/Object%20Pascal/VCL/Skia4Delphi). I believe you the mentioned sample can answer many of your recent questions about Skia4Delphi